# Hoops Exchange: file parsing problem on Linux

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, lib, hoops

I am trying to integrate Hoops Exchange 22.1 into my Qt 5.15.2 project on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.
The problem is that for some STEP files the coordinates are not parsed. Although those same STEP files open without problems on Windows. Interesting that the same problem is present with Polygonica and 3mf Lib.

My qmake file:

```
    QT -= gui

    CONFIG += c++17 console

    SOURCES + main.cpp
    
    qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
    else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
    !isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libs/include/hoops
    LIBS += -ldl
```

Maybe I missed something when connecting the library?

Comment: You should not use use qmake these days for Qt applications, but cmake.

Comment: On Windows, you do not seem to set the target path, like for qnx and non-android unix. Also, what do you mean by "for some STEP files the coordinates are not parsed"? Please clarify your question.